# How can I color commands instead of text?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, colors, ubuntu-16.04

I'm currently trying to get a basic script of about 4-5 commands such as ifconfig, uname -a, and commands alike in a script and have them colored differently.

So far, I've learned there are a million ways to color text. I finally got my text to be colored but instead of displaying the information it echo the actual "uname -a" in color.

This  used [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/qagsu/easy_colors_for_shell_scripts_color_library/) method to get the color working:

[This is my code input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gep3T.png)
[This is my code output, notice that the system and kernel information isn't displayed. Why is this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foI3X.png)

Comment: please post your code here instead of linking screenshots

Comment: There are probably less than a million different ways, but that method is definitely not the best.  To get a red "foo", use `tput setaf 1; echo foo; tput sgr0`

Answer (score 0):

You are currently outputting the string `uname -a` instead of executing it. You could put it into backticks to execute as well, but I think this would simpler:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -en "\e[31m"
uname -a
```